# disappearing files on desktop

Tags: recordmydesktop

I have upgraded my Ubuntu desktop from 14.04 to 14.10.After that,my files on my desktop disappearing but they are present in desktop folder.

I solved this problem by disabling wallpaper in compiz (CCSM).

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu Gnome 14.10, in the Tweak Tool enable 'Icons on Desktop' under Desktop

In Ubuntu 14.10, use `dconf-editor` and change the setting of Org->Gnome->Desktop->Background->Show-Desktop-Icons